# matching first word from a string

Tags: r

I have following R programs.

```
Test<-"CLC2" %in% "CLC2,CLC2,CLC2"
Test
Test1<-"CLC2" %in% "CLC2"
Test1
```

In first case, I want also get logical condition to be true as it matches to first word (required in my case).

Comment: Maybe also `'CLC2' == sub(",.*", "", "CLC2,CLC2,CLC2")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a word in a string and (if necessary) check if it is the first word of a string

```
gregexpr(pattern = "CLC2","CLC2,CLC2,CLC2")[[1]][1] == 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
"CLC2" %in% c("CLC2", "CLC2", "CLC2")
# [1] TRUE
```

or

```
"CLC2" %in% strsplit("CLC2,CLC2,CLC2", ",")[[1]]
# [1] TRUE
```

The 2nd one splits your string at every `,` character.

### Edit

It you just want to look at the first value, then it should be

```
"CLC2" %in% strsplit("CLC2,CLC2,CLC2", ",")[[1]][1]
"CLC2" %in% c("CLC2", "CLC2", "CLC2")[1]
```

as pointed out by @PierreLafortune. In that case, you don't need `%in%` but could also use `==` as you are just comparing one value to another value.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
 grepl('\\<CLC2\\>', unlist(strsplit("CLC2,CLC2,CLC2", ","))[1])
#[1] TRUE
```